# I have a classifier, now I want to identify best parameters

Tags: feature-selection, supervised-learning

I have data which I have classified using many supervised classifiers (using matlabs classification learner). I am classifying a Pass/Failed test vector with 50 different variables\features. I have several classifies that work well with a 95% accuracy at identifying the test from the features so I know the data can Identify pass/fail criteria.

I would like to identify which features are best at classifying the the pass/fail test vector if possible. I don't know if that is possible, if it is can I identify which features are best\most useful to the classifier?

I can use boosted\bagged trees or KNN as these worked well in classifing. How would I find the most useful parameters in one of these classifiers?

Comment: It depends on the classifier you use.  If you use a linear classifier, then generally the weights will be proportional to the importance of the corresponding attribute.   A linear SVM, for example, is a good candidate.  Other classifiers, such as Boosted Trees, will also provide you with a list of the most discriminating attributes.

Comment: The linear SVM's did not work, Boosted\Bagged trees did and also KNN. How would I find the most discriminating attributes?